# idle time and user time as negative value?

Tags: node.js, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm monitoring the CPU usage of my NodeJS application by the means of the `os.cpus()` function. When printing the return values of the function, I noticed some cores show negative values for user time and idle time. Is that even possible?

Edit:

Here is one of the CPUs in the returned object of that function call.

```
{ model: 'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E7540  @ 2.00GHz',
    speed: 1064,
    times: { 
        user: -599586196,
        nice: 46900,
        sys: 726751700,
        idle: -1356274912,
        irq: 1000 
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was due to a conversion error in the file `node_os.cc` in the /src folder of Node.JS. The problem and the solution are shown here https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/50e88d0. As a matter of fact, I was using an old version of node (0.8.12). Upgrading to the latest version fixed the bug.